# Converting hex values within a string to their string equivalent

Tags: string, for-loop, replace, hex, type-conversion

So, I've been looking around SO and a few other sites for a solid method of converting hex values embedded in normal strings (eg. The '/' are in the string as '\x2F') and wasn't able to find a solution that specifically fit my needs.

What I ended up doing was writing a bit of code myself to handle this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{
    string hexString = i.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');
    string searchString = @"\x" + hexString;

    if (response.Contains(searchString))
    {
        int charValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexString, 16);
        string character = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue);
        response = response.Replace(searchString, character);
    }
}
```

My question is this:

Is this a good way of going about it?

Any perticular drawbacks to me using this?

The purpose of this code is to take a string like:
"previous content...http:\x2F\x2Fwww.google.com...after content"
and convert it to:
"previous content...http://www.google.com...after content"